# Как сделать двухцветный бордер через фоновый градиент?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать нестандартный бордер через фоновый градиент?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создайте див блок, пропишите ему бэкграунд с таким градиентом, внутри Данного блока создайте другой див блок с бэкграундом белого цвета и паддингом приблизительно 5-10 пикселей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Прозрачность блока присутствует. "Резиновость" можно проверить ухватив блок за правый нижний угол.*

---

Для прямых углов:

### border-image

```css
h1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(#000 50%, #ff0 50%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  
  /* Only for demo --> */ overflow: hidden; resize: both;
}

/* Only for demo --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background:center / cover url(https://picsum.photos/id/868/960/540) no-repeat;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center}
```

```html
<h1>Двухцветная граница</h1>
```

Для скруглённых углов:

### ::before & ::after

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5em;
  
  /* Only for demo --> */ overflow: hidden; resize: both;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; z-index: -1;
  height: 50%; width: 100%;
  border: 4px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1::before {
  top: 0;
  border-color: #000;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
h1::after {
  bottom: 0;
  border-color: #f96;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 1em 1em;
}

/* Only for demo --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background:center / cover url(https://picsum.photos/id/868/960/540) no-repeat;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center}
```

```html
<h1>Двухцветная граница</h1>
```

### background & *-gradient()

```css
h1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: 
    0% 1em / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#000, #000), 
    0% 0% / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, #0000 calc(1em - 4px), #000 calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0000 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    50% 0% / calc(100% - 2em) 4px linear-gradient(#000, #000), 
    100% 0 / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, #0000 calc(1em - 4px), #000 calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0000 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    100% 1em / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#000, #000), 
    100% calc(100% - 1em) / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#090, #090), 
    0 100% / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, #0900 calc(1em - 4px), #090 calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0900 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    50% 100% / calc(100% - 2em) 4px linear-gradient(#090, #090), 
    100% 100% / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, #0900 calc(1em - 4px), #090 calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0900 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    0% calc(100% - 1em) / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#090, #090);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Only for demo --> */ overflow: hidden; resize: both;
}

/* Only for demo --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background:center / cover url(https://picsum.photos/id/868/960/540) no-repeat;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center}
```

```html
<h1>Двухцветная граница</h1>
```

Для углов другой формы:

```css
h1 {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: 
    0% 1em / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#000, #000),
    0% 0% / 1em 1em linear-gradient(135deg, #0000 calc(50% - 1px), #000 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 3px), #0000 calc(50% + 3px)), 
    50% 0% / calc(100% - 2em) 4px linear-gradient(#000, #000), 
    100% 0 / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0%, #0000 calc(1em - 4px), #000 calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0000 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    100% 1em / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#000, #000), 
    100% calc(100% - 1em) / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#0af, #0af), 
    0 100% / 1em 1em radial-gradient(circle at 0% 100%, #0af0 calc(1em - 4px), #0af calc(1em - 3.5px) 1em, #0af0 calc(1em + 1px)), 
    50% 100% / calc(100% - 2em) 4px linear-gradient(#0af, #0af),
    100% 100% / 1em 1em linear-gradient(315deg, #0af0 calc(50% - 1px), #0af calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 3px), #0af0 calc(50% + 3px)), 
    0% calc(100% - 1em) / 4px calc(50% - 1em) linear-gradient(#0af, #0af);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Only for demo --> */ overflow: hidden; resize: both;
}

/* Only for demo --> */ body{margin:0;min-height:100vh;background:center / cover url(https://picsum.photos/id/868/960/540) no-repeat;display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center}
```

```html
<h1>Двухцветная граница</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Один из вариантов как это реализовать](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/multi-colored-css-borders/)

Думаю в вашем варианте надо переделать под спаны внутри

```css
.ost-multi-header::after{
  content: '';
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ed8034 0%,#ed8034 33%,#feb123 33%,#feb123 66%,#2184cd 66%,#2184cd 100%) , 
  linear-gradient(to top, #ed8034 0%,#ed8034 33%,#feb123 33%,#feb123 66%,#2184cd 66%,#2184cd 100%);
}

.ost-multi-header{
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
height: 100px;
width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class ="ost-multi-header">Some text</div>
```

[Вот еще один вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850419/how-to-create-multi-color-border-with-css):

```css
.fancy-border {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align:center;
  border-top: 5px solid;
  border-image:   linear-gradient(to right, grey 25%, yellow 25%, yellow 50%,red 50%, red 75%, teal 75%) 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="fancy-border">
  my content
</div>
```

UPD:

[Вот прям как у вас вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/L886hrds/)

```css
.content {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
    background: rgba(52,117,247,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,117,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,117,247,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(52,117,247,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(52,117,247,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(230,214,39,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(230,214,39,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,117,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,117,247,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,117,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,117,247,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(52,117,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,117,247,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(52,117,247,1) 0%, rgba(52,117,247,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 50%, rgba(230,214,39,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3475f7', endColorstr='#e6d627', GradientType=1 );
    padding:4px;
}
.content div{
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'content'><div></div></div>
```